# How to install node.js and npm on Ubuntu terminal using WSL2 in windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, windows-10, wsl-2

I have problem with installing node.js and npm on my Ubuntu terminal (WSL2).

I tried to follow this instructions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/blob/docs/hub/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl.md

Also see some videos on YouTube, but every time I have same error.

First, I run this command:

`sudo apt-get install curl`

after I am trying to install nvm, with this command :

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash`

after that it tells, that nvm is installed, but shows some errors(I will include img)
and after that, I can't run this command to verify versions of node.js and npm :

```
command -v nvm  //or this command 
nvm ls
```

I already installed node.js in my windows, and when I open git bash and run this commands node -v and npm -v it shows me, which versions are installed.
But as I use Ubuntu terminal with fish, I wanted to install node.js and npm on it too. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it is installed. All OP needs to do is restart the terminal.

In my case, I've installed `nvm` with this instead

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
```

Then restarted the terminal, and it is working.

Below will share the full process I've been through to install Node.js in WSL.

---

First of all, make sure one has WSL installed [by following this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install). In this case OP already did that, so, just in case, would update the system's package

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, the following will install Node.js on WSL:

1. Install cURL (a tool used for downloading content from the internet in the command-line)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install curl
   ```
2. Install nvm (there are alternatives to nvm - see the first note below) ([Source](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating))

   ```
   curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
   ```

   Verify the installation with `command -v nvm` (it should output `nvm`)

   [image]

   Check Node versions available with `nvm ls`.
3. Install Node.js.

   There are various options to do that. Here will only consider installing:

   a) Current stable version (recommended for PRD):

   ```
   nvm install --lts
   ```

   [image]

   b) Current release:

   ```
   nvm install node
   ```
4. Check Node versions available

   ```
   nvm ls
   ```

   [image]
5. Verify Node.js installation `node --version` (or `node -v`).

   [image]
6. Verify npm installation with `npm --version`

   [image]

---

**Notes**

- One might have to restart the terminal after each installation.
- [Additional trouble shooting notes on Linux](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-linux).
- There are alternatives to nvm, such as `n`, `fnm`,... ([more about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl#alternative-version-managers))
- [Using Git on WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-git).
- [Helpful VSCode extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl#helpful-vs-code-extensions).
- One can also use Node.js with Docker containers remote on WSL. [Read more about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-containers).
- For more about it, [read Microsoft's official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl).

Comment: *All OP needs to do is restart the terminal.* (that worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be because you need to restart your terminal, this is one of the troubleshooting tips given from the [NVM github page](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-linux).

There are not any errors when downloading so it is probably just that the .bashrc file was updated but not ran (you should be able to use `source ~/.bashrc` instead of restarting)

Comment: after entering : source ~/.bashrc; it throw error :

~/.bashrc (line 6): 'case' builtin not inside of switch block
case $- in
^
from sourcing file ~/.bashrc
source: Error while reading file '/home/rostorm/.bashrc'

I also restart Terminal ,but same problem .

when I enter **command -v nvm** command nothing happens and 
**nvm ls** throws error  Command 'nvm' not found